# How to register a Function in Sqlite in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, sqlite

So the first what I found was that

```
if ($dbhandle = sqlite_open('mysqlitedb', 0666, $sqliteerror)) {
    sqlite_create_function($sqlite_db, "sqrt", "sqrt", 1);
```

But I get undefined for sqlite_open. I tried

```
$dbhandle = SQLite3::open('mysqlitedb')
```

But now I get the message: SQLite 3 not found.

My problem is that I need to register the SQRT function for my selectRaw Query in Laravel.

Comment: You need to install/enable sqllite extension for your php. What is your Operating System?

Comment: macOs high sierra and I've got  php 7.1.11

Comment: try run `php -m` to check if sqlite is listed. If not you should install it.

Comment: @DharmaSaputra it is (sqlite3). With php -i sqlite3

SQLite3 support => enabled
SQLite3 module version => 7.1.11
SQLite Library => 3.15.1

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
sqlite3.extension_dir => no value => no value

Comment: Aah. I forgot. You should also install `sqlite3` binary on your macOs. Have you install it?